# Popup modal with JS and PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've got a gallery where I have some buttons to filter the images by category. When you click an image it pops up a modal and shows the picture. It works when I open it up (at first it shows all the images) and when I choose a option 2021, but with other options it does not work. The strange thing is that when I click an image from (for example) option 2020, the modal does not show up, but when I click option 2021 the modal with the right picture shows up.
The buttons look like this:

```
<button data-filter=".2020">2020</button>
<button data-filter=".2021">2021</button>
```

I read the picture's names from mysql database and shows it with a while loop with php.

```
query starts
echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 special-grid '; echo $row["category"];  echo '">
...
<img id="myImg'; echo $db; $db++; echo'" src="gallery/'; echo $row["picturename"]; 
echo'" class="img-fluid" alt="Image" width="480" height="380">
query ends
```

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<img class="modal-content" id="img01">
<div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
for (let i = 0; i < <?php echo $sizeofgallery ?>; i++) {
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
   var img = document.getElementById("myImg" + i);
   img.onclick = function () {
       modal.style.display = "block";
       modalImg.src = this.src;
   }
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
   modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: can you look at the source code view for the page and copy the html that is relevant to your gallery as it does not look as though you have shared sufficient information/code to find the problem

Comment: for example `query starts
echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 special-grid '; echo $row["category"];  echo '">` seems incomplete